# Oracle BPEL Server: How to throw a Fault from a BPEL Java call-out?

Tags: oracle, bpel, bpelxexec

I'm calling a java class from BPEL via bpelx:exec. It would simplify things a lot if the class was able to throw a specific Fault (known to BPEL from one of its partner links). Let's call it AdapterFault. AdapterFault is generated by wsimport and subclasses Exception.

Here's the code within Embedded Java block:

```
Object wfr = getVariableData("inputVariable","request");
Object req = getVariableData("V_CreateServiceRequest","createTNRequestPart");

somepackage.EndpointIterator it =
new somepackage.EndpointIterator();

it.setWFRequest(wfr);
it.setPlatformName("MMSC");
it.setOperationName("createTN");
it.setRequest(req);

Object reply = it.invoke();

setVariableData("V_CreateServiceResponse","createTNResponsePart",reply);
```

When I declare the java method as throwing the AdapterFault, the BPEL refuses to deploy complaining that Exception is uncaught. It seems that Java callout step only declares BPELFault.

I'm only able to throw RuntimeException, which goes to CatchAll block instead of catch(AdapterFault).

Is there a simple way to throw a checked Fault from a java call-out?

Comment: Which version, do you mean a WSIF binding or a bpelx:exec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only BPELFault can be thrown:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=547192

But it could include the nested part, which is the "real" exception, which can be extracted in Catch block and re-thrown, if required.

I have implemented it today.

Gotchas:

- Catch block should catch one of the system exceptions, e.g. remoteFault.
- RuntimeFault.wsdl shall be imported (wsdl:import) into one of the partner WSDLs, otherwise a nasty error saying that BPELFault is not found will be thrown

BPELFault is rather limited in that it can only have code, message and detail elements, all plain text. Passing a complex nested fault type to BPEL is possible via bpelFault.setPart("myname",obj), but I don't know how to extract it from the BPELFault, as BPEL sees no "dynamic" parts. Code and message is enough for my purposes though.

Comment: Have a look at the fault-policies also, I am not sure if you can use that toghether with the bpelx:exec, they are pretty nice to use to humanIntervention. Here is a old blog I did on that. 
http://halfdecentoracle.blogspot.com/2007/08/soa-suite-10133-remote-fault-policies.html

Answer (score 1):

If it is a WSIF binding there are instructions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/juric-095829.html) under the "Exception Handling" heading, but that article is pretty old.

For bpelx:exec (I think) you need to catch the exception within the block and update a variable as such

> try {
>      ... do things
>
> }
>   catch(Exception ex) {
>
> addAuditTrailEntry("Exception message: " + ex.getMessage());
>
> setVariableData("V_CreateServiceException",...
>
> }
>
> }

Comment: Thanks, but WSIF seems an overkill for a simple callout. Could go that route if no other solution exist though.